# Does hibernate types library supports hibernate elasticsearch

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-types

I found "hibernate-types" library which provides support for complex fields like json etc in hibernate.

We need elasticsearch hibernate integration.

So I want to know whether it provides Hibernate Search+Elasticsearch support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Types is a library that provides types not integration with a search engine.

But Hibernate Search already provides a ElasticSearch integration:

Simply read the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch